# Critique of realloc() wrapper

Tags: c, memory-management, wrapper

Seeking code correctness and best practices.

I would like to re-allocate various amounts of memory (0 or more) such that on systems that may return `NULL` for an allocation of 0 does not falsely imply a memory allocation error.

Given:

- `void *` (with a valid value or NULL already)
- `size_t` (new desired size)

Receive:

- `void *` (new pointer)
- `int` (failure status)

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ReallocAndTest(char **Buf, size_t NewSize) {
  assert(Buf);
  char *NewBuf = realloc(*Buf, NewSize);
  if ((NewBuf == NULL) && (NewSize > 0)) {
    return 1;  // return failure
  }
  *Buf = NewBuf;
  return 0;
}
```

I came across the below references, which imply a `realloc()` return of `NULL` is not *always* a failure.  The lone special case occurs with `size` is 0.  The return value may or may not be `NULL`.

> C11dr 7.22.3.5 The realloc function 4 The `realloc` function returns a
>   pointer to the new object (which may have the same value as a pointer
>   to the old object), or a null pointer if the new object could not be
>   allocated.
>
> C11dr §J.1 Unspecified behavior.  — The amount of storage allocated by
>   a successful call to the calloc, malloc, or realloc function when 0
>   bytes was requested (7.22.3).
>
> C11dr §J.3.12 Implementation-defined behavior.  Whether the calloc,
>   malloc, and realloc functions return a null pointer or a pointer to an
>   allocated object when the size requested is zero (7.22.3).

- Discusses how a memory allocation of 0 is useful.
  Answer: when a routine has a `malloc(size)`, testing for `size != 0` is not needed.
  [what's the point in malloc(0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022335/whats-the-point-in-malloc0/2022402#2022402)
- Asks if `realloc(ptr), 0)` is the same as `free(ptr)`.
  Answer: Not necessarily.
  [What happens if I re-alloc and the new size is 0. Is this equivalent with a free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546572/what-happens-if-i-re-alloc-and-the-new-size-is-0-is-this-equivalent-with-a-free)
- Allocation wrapper set.
  Answer: Does not address `realloc(ptr, 0)`.
  [Are these memory-allocation wrapper functions kosher with all C compilers?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26656/are-these-memory-allocation-wrapper-functions-kosher-with-all-c-compilers)

---

[Answer]

1. Use `void*` rather than `char *`.
2. With a 0 size, avoid returning the implementation defined
   ..a) `NULL` or
   ..b) `ptr` that cannot be referenced.
   and return a pointer to insure only 1 of the 2 is ever returned.

On point #2, I only slightly favor returning `NULL`.

Comment: I already see I should be using `void *` rather than `char *`.

Comment: For semantic consistency, you might want to change 0 to FALSE, 1 to TRUE and int to bool(C++) or bool_t/BOOL/BOOLEAN (or whatever standard bool type you're using in your C program). That will make it more clear to callers what they should expect the function to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Standard naming convention in C is usually `lower_case_with_underscore`.
2. You should be using `void *` rather than `char *`
3. I would consider making the return value deterministic when the new size is 0 by always returning `NULL` rather than the implementation defined behaviour (which could technically be a pointer which is not `NULL` but still not allowed to be dereferenced). `free` guarantees by spec that `free(NULL)` is legal.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the standard in 1.  Where may I find it?

Comment: @chux: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#C_and_C.2B.2B and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722112/what-are-the-most-common-naming-conventions-in-c

Comment: The wiki says "standard library identifiers are mostly lowercase" and this is not a standard library identifier.  Sorry if the "wrapper" description misled.  The SO post reflect various conventions but not a standard.  The C standard _does_ distinguish between upper and lower case letter in all identifiers, so this implies that upper case usage is not verboten.  The SO post did stress _consistency_.  I concur with your naming convention of trying to be standard.

Comment: Yes, naming conventions are always subjective. However `PascalCase` for local variables and function parameters is rather unusual.

Comment: This is a good "patch critique" for the given wrapper.  The other answer explains a better wrapper.

Answer (score 5):

With the variety of behaviors exhibited by different implementations, I think the only safe thing is to test for zero size before the `realloc` call and set a minimum allocation (eg 1 byte).

Note that `realloc` will probably set `errno` to `ENOMEM` when it fails, but I don't think this is guaranteed.

Comment: `ENOMEM` appears to be in Linux and not the C standard.  It is surprising that a memory allocation error does not generate a error code per the C standard.  Maybe a history thing.

Comment: +1 Checking for 0 before calling realloc is indeed the correct approach. Avoid writing code that relies on unspecified or impl.defined behavior. One of the point of writing a wrapper is to get rid of such things.

Comment: I (also) suggest if someone calls your_malloc() or your_realloc() with size 0, you should call malloc() or realloc() with size 1.  That way you always have a distinct pointer.  Some code may benefit from the assumption that distict allocated objects have distinct addresses; and of course it's not good to be confused between success and failure!  I did this in my malloc and realloc wrappers:  http://sam.nipl.net/libb/alloc.b  Additionally, this allows your_malloc and your_realloc to be signature compatible with the originals.